# Lock pthread_mutex_t in structure C

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, structure, mutex

I have one `pthread_mutex_t` aka lock in a structure and I create 2 structures.

1. are those the same lock? Or are they a completely different lock?
2. I have a function that uses the lock of the structure, can the one structure detect if the other structure lock is used?

Comment: I have one int in a structure and I create 2 structures. Are they the same int? Or are they completely different ints? I have a function that uses the int of one structure, can the one structure detect if the other structure int is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *are those the same lock?Or are they completly different lock?*

It deppends, if you have a pointer you can use the same mutex in both structures, if not, they are copies, using one will not reflect on the other.

> *I have a function that uses the lock of the structure, can the one structure detect if the other structure lock is used?*

Again, if it's a pointer to the same mutex it's shared by both structures,  lock/unlock is detected by both, if not, locking or unlocking one will have no effect on the other.

Comment: Thank you one more question because i use it in only one file would it be better o create a lock in that file? Or use a lock with a pointer?

Comment: @MastReyheart, if it's a global variable, ***i.e.*** declared and initialized at file level, the same lock is reckognized by all the functions in that file, if it's declared at function level you should pass it by pointer for it to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Locks are no different from `int`s or any other members of a structure.

Q: I have one int in a structure and I create 2 structures. Are they the same int?
A: No they are not. Each structure has its own int.

Q: I have a function that uses the int of one structure, can the one structure detect if the other structure int is used?
A: No it cannot, because each structure has its own int.

If I wanted one int shared by all the structures, I could make it a global variable.

Comment: Thank you i understand now :)